# Eclipse cdt,find References doesn't work for c++ project

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Generally, under jdt, when I select a method, right click, then References->Workspace from context menu, Eclipse will show me all wheres that referred this method. But this function seems not work for C++ project (Eclipse 4.3+cdt 8.3), and I am sure the method that I selected is referred by some places in my current C++ project. I doubted it is an indexing issue, but finding declaration and implementation works. I have never tried this feature in Eclipse before. So,can somebody tell me

1. isn't this feature provided by cdt at all or
2. are there some issues of my eclipse that caused this function doesn't work? If so, how to diagnose this problem?

Comment: This feature is very buggy. The whole indexer is. Rebuild the index and pray is your best bet unfortunately

Comment: thanks,can't believe it.